# How to plot a 2-Graph (Königsberg Graph, Euler)

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to plot a 2-graph, the Königsberg graph. I've got this:
V={A,B,C,D} the set of vertices
E={e1={A,B}, e2={A,B}, e3={A,D}, e4={C,D}, e5={B,C}, e6={B,C}, e7={B,D}}
the set of nodes (axis, aristas)

Thanks

Comment: What is a 2-graph?

Comment: @percusse Maybe the OP means a planar graph...

Comment: What have you tried? Do you know of the `graphs` TikZ library (section 19 in the doc)?

Comment: @percusse 2-graph is a graph where every node has got 2 axis

Comment: It's meant to emphasize that this is not a math site so it needs some context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with `pst-eucl`, if you want to give a try at `pstricks`. Here is a short code, compilable with `pdflatex` if you use the `shell-escape` (TeX Live, MacTeX) or `--enable-write18` (MiKTeX) switch:

```
\documentclass[12pt, pdf, x11names]{article}%

\usepackage{pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-1, -1.2)(2, 1.2)
\psset{linewidth=0.5pt, linecolor=SteelBlue3, fillcolor=SteelBlue3, PointNameSep=0.8em}
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=none, PointName=none](0.5,-0.5){O1}(-0.5, -0.5){P1}(0.5,0.5){O2}(-0.5,0.5){P2}
\pstGeonode[PointSymbol=o, PosAngle={180,180,180,0}](0,-1){A}(0,0){B}(0,1){C}(1.5,0){D}
\ncline{A}{D} \ncline{B}{D} \ncline{C}{D}
\pstArcOAB{O1}{B}{A}\pstArcOAB{P1}{A}{B}
\pstArcOAB{O2}{C}{B}\pstArcOAB{P2}{B}{C}
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've got a lot of error messages with miktex2.9. I've installed all pst packages.

Comment: @Tobal: I forgot to mention that you have to launch `pdflatex` with the `--enable-write18` switch. I suppose it's the problem. Could you confirm that, please?

Comment: this is not the problem. In a message I obtain SteelBlue3 is not defined.

Comment: Strange… It's defined in the `x11names` module of `xcolor` (p. 40 of the doc) wich is loaded by `pstricks`, which is loaded by `pst-eucl`. That's why it is among the class options (to avoid  optionsloading conflicts). Just in case, load `xcolor` (but `x11names` must remain a class option).

Comment: I've added --enable-write18 pdf and x11names and I view the pdf but without the graph. TeXStudio tells me that \pstGeonode and \pstArcOAB are instructions not recognized. Where can I upload my code free and you see it?

Comment: @Tobal: I can give my professional email, but where? Btw the instructions you mention are defined in `pst-eucl`. Is this package installed on your system? It is not part of `basic` MiKTeX.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/17532/discussion-between-bernard-and-tobal).